# inTune APP app is installed but there is a newer version available?

Tags: intune, ipados, apple-vpp

I have Microsoft Outlook assigned to my iPad estate with inTune and a number of devices are showing "App installation failed" with the following error that I cannot find a resolution for.

```
Error code: 0x87D13B9F
An app update is available. Available apps can be updated using Company Portal and required apps will auto-update on device sync.
Suggested remediation
This code is returned when a VPP app is installed but there is a newer version available.
```

When looking at **Apps > iOS/iPadOS > Microsoft Outlook** it is showing as iOS volume purchase program app and is assigned to an AzureAD group, which the users of the affected devices are in (as that group also has the appropriate Microsoft license for Exchange) and the settings for deployment are the same for other installed apps (including Teams, Word and Excel).

I have gone to **Tenant Administration > Connectors & Tokens > Apple VPP Tokens** and my token, which is valid until end of 2022; clicked to "SYNC" that (waited at least a day)

From **Apple Business Manager > Apps and Books** I can see Microsoft Outlook is present and attached the location, with a matching number of licenses (plenty of spares). There doesn't appear to be anything in ABM relating to the particular version of the app, not 'updates' of it.

Any clue as to what I may have missed would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the VPP-token you are using has automatic updates enabled?

Tenant Administration > Connectors & Tokens > Apple VPP Tokens, Select your token and it should be under settings.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."